# when I run my coding, an error message appears: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. how to fix it?

Tags: android

when I run my coding, an error message appears: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. and the value obtained from ReadDataNodeTask does not appear.
how to fix it?
please help me.

and this is my code:

```
package com.farid.starsmaps.rute;

public class RuteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, TaskLoadedCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    TextView TextLatitude, TextLongitude, TextTujuan, Status_Asal, TextLatAwal, TextLonAwal,
            TextLatAkhir, TextLonAkhir, TextJarak, TextNamaNodeAwal, TextNamanNodeAkhir, TextJarakNode;
    String latitude, longitude, tujuan, lat_awal, lon_awal, lat_akhir, lon_akhir;
    ListView list;
    Button BtnHitung;
    List<String> valueIdNode = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valueNamaNode = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valueLatitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valueLongitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    ProgressDialog  pDialog;
    JSONArray JsonArrayNode = null;
    JSONArray daftarNodeAwal, daftarNodeAkhir, daftarJarak = null;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private List<LocationModel> mListMarker = new ArrayList<>();
    private Polyline currentPolyline;
    private MarkerOptions place1, place2;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    private Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    Spinner spinnerTujuan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rute);
        //getJSON(Konfigurasi.URL_READ_TOKO);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        list = findViewById(R.id.ListJalur);

        TextLatitude    = findViewById(R.id.TxtLat);
        TextLongitude   = findViewById(R.id.TxtLon);
        TextTujuan      = findViewById(R.id.TxtTujuan);
        Status_Asal     = findViewById(R.id.StatusAsal);
        BtnHitung       = findViewById(R.id.ButtonHitung);
        TextLatAwal     = findViewById(R.id.Lat_awal);
        TextLonAwal     = findViewById(R.id.Lon_awal);
        TextLatAkhir    = findViewById(R.id.Lat_akhir);
        TextLonAkhir    = findViewById(R.id.Lon_akhir);
        TextJarak       = findViewById(R.id.TxtJarak);
        TextNamaNodeAwal= findViewById(R.id.TxtNamaNodeAwal);
        TextNamanNodeAkhir= findViewById(R.id.TxtNamaNodeAkhir);
        TextJarakNode   = findViewById(R.id.TxtJarakNode);
        spinnerTujuan   = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTujuan);
        latitude        = TextLatitude.getText().toString();
        longitude       = TextLongitude.getText().toString();

        BtnHitung.setOnClickListener(this);

        new ReadDataNodeTask().execute();

        //Mengolah data lokasi menggunakan GPS
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 101);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tujuan = TextTujuan.getText().toString();
        latitude = TextLatitude.getText().toString();
        longitude = TextLongitude.getText().toString();
        boolean isEmptyFields = false;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(latitude)){
            isEmptyFields = true;
            TextLatitude.setError("Latitude Asal belum didapat");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(longitude)){
            isEmptyFields = true;
            TextLongitude.setError("Longitude Asal belum didapat");
        }
        if (!isEmptyFields) {
            Status_Asal.setText("Koordinat Asal telah didapat");

            new ReadDataNodeTask().execute();
            new ReadJarak().execute();

            double lat11 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLatAwal.getText().toString().trim());
            double long11 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLonAwal.getText().toString().trim());
            double lat22 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLatAkhir.getText().toString().trim());
            double long22 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLonAkhir.getText().toString().trim());
            String nawal = TextNamaNodeAwal.getText().toString().trim();
            String nakhir = TextNamanNodeAkhir.getText().toString().trim();
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
            mMap.clear();

            LatLng awal = new LatLng(lat11, long11);
            LatLng akhir = new LatLng(lat22, long22);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(awal).title(nawal));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(akhir).title(nakhir));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(awal,10));

            double j = 111.319;
            double euclid = (sqrt(pow((lat11 - lat22), 2) + pow((long11 - long22), 2))) * j;
            String h = String.valueOf(df.format(euclid));
            String koma = String.valueOf(TextJarakNode.getText());
            String hasil = h.substring(-3);
            TextJarak.setText(h + " Km");
            System.out.println("Jarak Node = " + hasil);
            //getAllDataLocationLatLng();

            place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(awal).title("Location 1");
            place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(akhir).title("Location 2");
            String url = getUrl(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition(),"driving");
            new FetchURL(RuteActivity.this).execute(url,"driving");
        }
    }

    private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest, String directionMode) {
        double lat11 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLatAwal.getText().toString().trim());
        double long11 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLonAwal.getText().toString().trim());
        double lat22 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLatAkhir.getText().toString().trim());
        double long22 = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLonAkhir.getText().toString().trim());
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + lat11 + "," + long11;
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + lat22 + "," + long22;
        // Mode
        String mode = "mode=" + directionMode;
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&avoid=tolls&" + mode;
        // Output format
        //String output = "json";
        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json" + "?" + parameters + "&key=AIzaSyBTVcGt2fegGE6taEgiwhrQL7QWU5dgJC0";
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskDone(Object... values) {
        if (currentPolyline != null)
            currentPolyline.remove();
        currentPolyline = mMap.addPolyline((PolylineOptions) values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Memulai Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void getAllDataLocationLatLng(){
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Menampilkan data marker ..");
        dialog.show();

        ApiNodeService apiComeService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiNodeService.class);
        Call<ListLocationModel> call = apiComeService.getAllLocation();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListLocationModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ListLocationModel> call, retrofit2.Response<ListLocationModel> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                mListMarker = response.body().getmData();
                initMarker(mListMarker);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ListLocationModel> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initMarker(List<LocationModel> listData){
        double latAwal = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLatAwal.getText());
        double lonAwal = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLonAwal.getText());
        double latAkhir = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLatAkhir.getText());
        double lonAkhir = Double.parseDouble((String) TextLonAkhir.getText());
        LatLng awal = new LatLng(latAwal, lonAwal);
        LatLng akhir = new LatLng(latAkhir, lonAkhir);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(awal));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(akhir));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(awal,10));
        //iterasi semua data dan tampilkan markernya
//        for (int i = 0; i < mListMarker.size(); i++) {
//            //set latlng nya
//            LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLongitude()));
//            //tambahkan markernya
//            Marker markers = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(mListMarker.get(i).getNode()));
//            //set latlng index ke 0
//            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-7.346961, 112.739786);
//            //lalu arahkan zooming ke marker index ke 0
//            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 11.0f));

//            String str_origin = "origin=" + TextLatAwal + "," + TextLonAwal;
//            String str_dest = "destination=" + TextLatAkhir + "," + TextLonAkhir;
//            String sensor = "sensor=false";
//            String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;
//            String output = "json";
//            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters+ "&key=" +getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
//
//            Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
//            FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();
//            FetchUrl.execute(url);
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location !=null){
            TextLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            TextLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

            Location mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude)).zoom(16).build();

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            //menghentikan pembaruan lokasi
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class ReadDataNodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RuteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mengambil koordinat Node Tujuan...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {
            Rute tempMarkerAwal = new Rute();
            List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try {
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Konfigurasi.URL_NODE_AWAL,"POST", parameter);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + json);

                int success = json.getInt(Konfigurasi.TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) { //Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1)
                    //Getting Array of daftar_mhs
                    daftarNodeAwal = json.getJSONArray(Konfigurasi.TAG_NODE_AWAL);
                    //looping through All daftar_mhs
                    for (int i = 0; i < daftarNodeAwal.length() ; i++){
                        JSONObject c = daftarNodeAwal.getJSONObject(i);
                        //tempMarkerAwal = new Rute();
                        String id_node      = tempMarkerAwal.setId_Node(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_ID_NODE));
                        String nama_awal    = tempMarkerAwal.setNama_Node(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_NAMA_AWAL));
                        String lat_node_awal= tempMarkerAwal.setLat_Node(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_LAT_NODE));
                        String lon_node_awal= tempMarkerAwal.setLon_Node(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_LON_NODE));

                        TextNamaNodeAwal.setText(nama_awal);
                        TextLatAwal.setText(lat_node_awal);
                        TextLonAwal.setText(lon_node_awal);
                    }
                    return "OK";
                }else{
                    //Tidak Ada Record Data (SUCCESS = 0)
                    return "no results";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception Caught";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Gagal mengambil data node, tidak bisa terhubung ke server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("no results")){
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Data empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Data node sudah muncul", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            new getDataNodeTujuan().execute();
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class getDataNodeTujuan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RuteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mengambil data...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //Membuat Service "ServiceHandler"
            NodeHandler ah = new NodeHandler();

            // Memanggil URL untuk mendapatkan respon data
            String jsonStr = ah.makeServiceCall(Konfigurasi.URL_READ_NODE, NodeHandler.GET); //siswaManager.php?mode=getAllDataSiswa

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Mendapatkan data Array JSON
                    JsonArrayNode = jsonObj.getJSONArray("values");

                    ArrayList<Node> listDataNode = new ArrayList<Node>();
                    listDataNode.clear();

                    //Melakukan perulangan untuk memecah data
                    for (int i = 0; i < JsonArrayNode.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = JsonArrayNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        Node node = new Node();
                        node.setIdNode(obj.getString("id_node"));
                        node.setNamaNode(obj.getString("nama_node"));
                        node.setLatitude(obj.getString("latitude"));
                        node.setLongitude(obj.getString("longitude"));
                        listDataNode.add(node);
                    }

                    valueIdNode     = new ArrayList<String>();
                    valueNamaNode   = new ArrayList<String>();
                    valueLatitude   = new ArrayList<String>();
                    valueLongitude  = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listDataNode.size(); i++) {
                        valueIdNode.add(listDataNode.get(i).getIdNode());
                        valueNamaNode.add(listDataNode.get(i).getNamaNode());
                        valueLatitude.add(listDataNode.get(i).getLatitude());
                        valueLongitude.add(listDataNode.get(i).getLongitude());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            // Membuat adapter untuk spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapterNode = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RuteActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valueNamaNode);

            spinnerAdapterNode.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            //Mengaitkan adapter spinner dengan spinner yang ada di layout
            spinnerTujuan.setAdapter(spinnerAdapterNode);
            spinnerTujuan.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    String IdNode       = valueIdNode.get(position);
                    String NamaNode     = valueNamaNode.get(position);
                    String Latitude     = valueLatitude.get(position);
                    String Longitude    = valueLongitude.get(position);
                    TextTujuan.setText(IdNode);
                    TextLatAkhir.setText(Latitude);
                    TextLonAkhir.setText(Longitude);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // your code here
                }
            });
            new UpdateNodeAwal().execute();
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class UpdateNodeAwal extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RuteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {
            List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            try {
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Konfigurasi.URL_UPDATE_AWAL,"POST", parameter);

                int success = json.getInt(Konfigurasi.TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    return "OK";
                } else {
                    return "FAIL";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception Caught";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Gagal Mengupdate node awal, tidak bisa terhubung ke server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")){
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Gagal, Coba lagi...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Node awal terupdate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            new UpdateDataAwalAkhir().execute();
        }
    }

    //fungsi create data
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class UpdateDataAwalAkhir extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RuteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {

            List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Konfigurasi.TAG_TUJUAN, tujuan));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Konfigurasi.TAG_LATITUDE, latitude));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Konfigurasi.TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude));

            try {
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Konfigurasi.URL_INPUT,"POST", parameter);

                int success = json.getInt(Konfigurasi.TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    return "OK";
                } else {
                    return "FAIL";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception Caught";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Gagal Mengupdate data, tidak bisa terhubung ke server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")){
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Gagal, Coba lagi...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RuteActivity.this, "Sukses", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when I run my code, an error message appears. the error is Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doInBackground method in your ReadDataNodeTask is performing UI logic on the background thread:

```
TextNamaNodeAwal.setText(nama_awal);
TextLatAwal.setText(lat_node_awal);
TextLonAwal.setText(lon_node_awal);
```

You should wrap any UI logic here in a Handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // your UI code goes here
     }
});
```

See the documentation for more info on threading in an AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#the-4-steps

Answer (score 0):

It simply because you're doing UI related in [`doInBackground(Params...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) of AsyncTask.

You're doing the following:

```
class ReadDataNodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {

      ...

      // you must not do the UI changes here
      TextNamaNodeAwal.setText(nama_awal);
      TextLatAwal.setText(lat_node_awal);
      TextLonAwal.setText(lon_node_awal);

      ...
    }

}
```

You should doing it inside [`onPostExecute(Result)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)):

```
class ReadDataNodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     ...

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // should doing the UI changes inside this method.
     }
}
```